# Apple Mail & Entourage Client Detection

Tags: php, email, email-client

I've been figuring out how to track email picked up within Apple Mail and Entourage - I thought perhaps could use the user agent header like you can with Outlook and Thunderbird, but it appears not.

Example Entourage User Agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko)`

I know you can track with PHP, by using it within an image (and it will only track if images are shown).

Having looked at the user agent, the only different thing is that it shows webkit version - i'm not too sure (at least i couldn't find) if there were different Webkit versions for Entourage, Apple Mail, and so forth.

I've also been wondering if there is anything unique (in terms of CSS) that could be included to generate a track (eg. if Apple Mail v4, include this image, else include that image).

The question is, is there anyway to detect different versions of Apple Mail or Entourage? Or does anyone know of a list of Webkit versions/understand the Webkit numbering convention that correspond to either client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entourage and Apple Mail both use the AppleWebKit framework which is what is generating the user agent you see. It appears that Safari and Chrome add text at the end of the UA string, but Entourage and Apple Mail do not.

Comment: do you know if there are any differences to the UA if it were used in different versions of Apple Mail?

Comment: had to settle for it matching to "Apple Mail & Entourage" as opposed to separating them